# Oracle return difference result from the same user but difference windows user

Tags: oracle

I have two users on windows server

1. Administrator
2. devUser

Both can use SQL Developer to connect to Oracle 11g Server (Oracle e-Business suite) but in the same query (from synonym) they got the difference result: devUser got the correct result and Administrator got null in first three columns.

SELECT * from XXAUTO.XXFND_OU_COMPANY_V 
where ou_name like 'ASL%'

[Query Result from Administrator(Windows User)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX3bO.png)

Comment: what is the query both the users are executing? May be its because both are getting results from their respective schemas or administrator is getting the overall DB result... again depends on the table/view on which query is executed.

Comment: You'd need to show us the tables, the actual and expected outputs to get any usable help.

Comment: You might want to check that the code does not have any implicit date format conversions that depend on NLS settings.  If the code has a string like `'01/01/2000'` it may work differently depending on the configuration of their operating system and SQL Developer sessions.

Comment: SELECT * from XXAUTO.XXFND_OU_COMPANY_V 
where ou_name like 'ASL%'

Comment: XXAUTO.XXFND_OU_COMPANY_V is synonym

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the view has some form of VPD in place. Oracle supports Fine-Grained Access Control through its DBMS_RLS package, which despite the name allows us to implement security policies on columns as well as rows (since 10g). [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/network.1111/e16543/vpd.htm).

The common model is, when users connect to the database a LOGON trigger populates an application context with details about them. These details are used to generate as additional filters on tables and views which have security policies in place. You can confirm this by using the pertinent views: start with ALL_POLICIES and drill down depending on what you find.

It's possible the view implements a hand-rolled version of this (FGAC is an Enterprise Edition feature) but if you're using EBS that seems unlikely.

Another option is that your database is protected by Oracle Database Vault. This product is a chargeable extra to the EE license. It is a very powerful tool, and one of its uses is to prevent super users like sysadmins or DBAs abusing their privileges to look at sensitive data. It seems unlikely that an organisation would put Database Vault in place on a server that developers have access to but I offer this suggestion for completeness. [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/database-vault/index-085211.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all. 
Now I found the problem that is both user set the different Windows locale.